# No me cambia el valor a un elemento dinámico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inyecto dinamicamente con `JQuery` un `td` con la `class _totale1_` dentro de un `tr` con la `class _dir_` con el texto **'00'**.
`$("#ejemplo").append("<tr class='dir'> <td class='totale1'>00</td></tr>");`

Después le quiero cambiar el valor y ponerle **'fine'**: 
`$("tr.dir .totale1").text("fine");`

No me lo cambia.

Comment: Si sí, no hay ningún problema con el append. El problema está al intentar cambiar el valor de lo que el append inyecta.

Comment: Veo que has editado la pregunta añadiendo el id de la tabla o quizá del tbody, con eso debería ser suficiente, si mi respuesta de abajo no es de ayuda por favor publica el código junto con el HTML para realizar pruebas.

Comment: No quites los detalles y el código de tu pregunta, pues con la edición que hiciste aminoras la calidad de la misma y pareciera que no llevas nada hecho

Comment: Ah vale lo siento, aun no controlo mucho como va el sitio

Comment: He revertido los cambios para que la pregunta y la respuesta estén en consonancia. Si tienes otras dudas, crea una nueva pregunta

Comment: Tengo esta duda. Si en vez de poneros a hacer cambios que no sirven de nada, ¿podéis responderme a la pregunta?

Comment: No necesariamente quien edita la pregunta sabe especificamente como responder tu pregunta. Pero tal vez, mejorandola, alguien que sepa pueda entenderla y no perder el tiempo en tratar de entender que pasa para responderla, si no solo responderla. Tomarse el tiempo para mejorar tu pregunta tambien sirve para que encuentres una respuesta a tu problema. Tene en cuenta que si la pregunta no es facil de entender, tal vez alguien ni se moleste en contestarla.

Answer (score 7):

Al parecer estás realizando mal el append, te dejo todo un snippet para que pruebes dando clic a los botones, lo importante es mirar a qué elemento le estás realizando el append:

```js
$("#addValue").click(function(){
  $("#myTable tbody").append("<tr class='dir'> <td class='totale1'>00</td></tr>");  //Agregamos un nuevo tr
});

$("#changeText").click(function(){
  $("tr.dir td.totale1").text("Otro texto");  //Cambiamos el texto
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <th>Columna 1</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Valor 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="addValue">Añadir tr</button>
<button id="changeText">Cambiar texto</button>
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: No me resuelve la duda, lo siento

Comment: Por favor publica tu código HTML para dar una respuesta más precisa.